# Inherit SKShapeNode

Tags: swift, skshapenode

Why it's possible to instantiate a SKShapeNode like this

```
let circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)
```

But when i want to create a class that inherit form `SKShapeNode` i cant do something like this:

```
public class Player:SKShapeNode{

public var playerName : String
private var inventory: [enumObject]

init(nameOfPlayer:String, position:CGPoint, radious: CGFloat) {

super.init(circleOfRadius: radious)
self.position = position
self.fillColor = SKColor.white

playerName = nameOfPlayer

inventory = [enumObject]()
}

}
```

It says that this init is not the designed init for `SKShapeNode`, I searched about it but couldn't find the right way of creating this damn circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SKShapeNode.init(circleOfRadius:)` is a convenience initializer on `SKShapeNode` so you can't call it from a Swift initializer. Swift enforces the designated initializer pattern more strictly than Objective C does.

Unfortunately, it appears the designated initializer for `SKShapeNode` is just `init`, so you'll need to do something like this:

```
public class Player: SKShapeNode {
    public var playerName : String
    private var inventory: [enumObject]

    init(nameOfPlayer:String, position:CGPoint, radius: CGFloat) {
        playerName = nameOfPlayer
        inventory = [enumObject]()

        super.init()

        self.path = CGPath(ellipseIn: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius)), transform: nil)

        self.position = position
        self.fillColor = SKColor.white
    }

    // init?(coder:) is the other designated initializer that we have to support
    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

The code above works for subclassing `SKShapeNode`, but given the API that Apple provides and considering how your code might need to change in the future, it might make more sense to create an `SKNode` subclass that contains one or more `SKShapeNode`s. In this setup, if you wanted to represent the player as more than just a simple circle, you could simply add additional nodes to the player node.